# Problem detecing window border collision in SFML

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml, collision

I am trying to make my moving rectangle bounce off the window borders when it collides with them, however the rectangle is rotating. I'm not sure how to define my collision functions, this is what I came up with:

```
//left border collision
     if(rectangle.getPosition().y<0){
         rectangle.setPosition(rectangle.getPosition().x,0);
     //top border collision
     };
     if(rectangle.getPosition().x<0){
         rectangle.setPosition(0,rectangle.getPosition().y);
     };
     //right border collision
     if(rectangle.getPosition().y+rectangle.getGlobalBounds().width>WINDOW_W){
         rectangle.setPosition(rectangle.getPosition().y,WINDOW_W-rectangle.getGlobalBounds().width);
     };
     //bottom border collision
     if(rectangle.getPosition().x+rectangle.getGlobalBounds().height>WINDOW_H){
         rectangle.setPosition(WINDOW_H-rectangle.getGlobalBounds().height,rectangle.getPosition().y);
     };
```

The code detects some collision, but I think it's not taking the rotation of the rectangle into account.

There is my whole code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // create some shapes
    sf::CircleShape circle(100.0);
    circle.setPosition(100.0, 300.0);
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));

    sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(120.0, 60.0));
    rectangle.setPosition(500.0, 400.0);
    rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 50, 250));

    sf::ConvexShape triangle;
    triangle.setPointCount(3);
    triangle.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(0.0, 0.0));
    triangle.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(0.0, 100.0));
    triangle.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(140.0, 40.0));
    triangle.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
    triangle.setOutlineThickness(5);
    triangle.setPosition(600.0, 100.0);

    //clock function
    sf::Clock clock;

    //finding screen resolutions for collision
    int WINDOW_W = window.getSize().y;
    int WINDOW_H = window.getSize().x;

    //declaring moving speeds for the rectangle
    float rec_vel_x = 50;
    float rec_vel_y = 150;
    //delcaring speed of rotation of the rectangle
    float rec_ang_vel = 10;


    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        //Time elapsed function
         sf::Time elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();
         // getting elapsed time as float, needed fro the float function
         float el1 = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        // moving the rectangle per each elapsed second with the preset values
        rectangle.move(el1*rec_vel_x,el1*rec_vel_y);
        //rotating the rectangle
        rectangle.rotate(el1*rec_ang_vel);


        // draw everything here...
        window.draw(circle);
        window.draw(rectangle);
        window.draw(triangle);

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
        //game updates
         std::cout<<elapsed.asSeconds()<<std::endl;
         //extracting values for the collision
         //sf::FloatRect rectangle_bounds = rectangle.getGlobalBounds();
         //left border collision
         if(rectangle.getPosition().y<0){
             rectangle.setPosition(rectangle.getPosition().x,0);
         //top border collision
         };
         if(rectangle.getPosition().x<0){
             rectangle.setPosition(0,rectangle.getPosition().y);
         };
         //right border collision
         if(rectangle.getPosition().y+rectangle.getGlobalBounds().width>WINDOW_W){
             rectangle.setPosition(rectangle.getPosition().y,WINDOW_W-rectangle.getGlobalBounds().width);
         };
         //bottom border collision
         if(rectangle.getPosition().x+rectangle.getGlobalBounds().height>WINDOW_H){
             rectangle.setPosition(WINDOW_H-rectangle.getGlobalBounds().height,rectangle.getPosition().y);
         };
    }
    sf::FloatRect rectangle_bounds = rectangle.getGlobalBounds();
    std::cout << rectangle_bounds.top << " " << rectangle_bounds.left << " " ;
    std::cout << rectangle_bounds.width << " " << rectangle_bounds.height << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"wysokosc okna to: " << WINDOW_H << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"szerokosc okna to: " << WINDOW_W << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't implemented the bouncing yet, for now I want the rectangle not to go outside the window

Answer (score 0):

You've got xs and ys swapped in some places, remember that `setPosition()`, `getPosition()` take x first and then y.

Here's the fixed code:

```cpp
//left border collision
if(rectangle.getPosition().x<0){
     rectangle.setPosition(0,rectangle.getPosition().y);
};

//top border collision
if(rectangle.getPosition().y<0){
     rectangle.setPosition(rectangle.getPosition().x, 0);
};

//right border collision
if(rectangle.getPosition().x+rectangle.getGlobalBounds().width>WINDOW_W){
     rectangle.setPosition(WINDOW_W-rectangle.getGlobalBounds().width, rectangle.getPosition().y);
};

//bottom border collision
if(rectangle.getPosition().y+rectangle.getGlobalBounds().height>WINDOW_H){
     rectangle.setPosition(rectangle.getPosition().x, WINDOW_H-rectangle.getGlobalBounds().height);
};
```

Top and bottom borders stop the rectangle in y axis, hence we change y when it hits them. The case is analogical for left and right hand borders: x coordinates should be set while y stays the same.

Apparently, `WINDOW_H` and `WINDOW_W` are swapped as well, it should be:

```cpp
//finding screen resolutions for collision
int WINDOW_W = window.getSize().x;
int WINDOW_H = window.getSize().y;
```

EDIT: Fixed grammar errors and added a word about `WINDOW_H`.

Comment: I see, thank you for that, however the collision still will not be detected and the rectangle will go outside my window, do you have any solution for that  ?

Comment: There's a possibility, that `WINDOW_H` and `WINDOW_W` are swapped as well. Remember that width corresponds to x axis and height to y axis.

Comment: That appears to have fixed the top and bottom borders collision, however both the right and left borders seem to be moved to the left a few units.

Comment: I don't see any other purely mathematical errors, so I guess the cause might be that your rectangle is operated in order: move --> render --> update window. So every frame firstly your rectangle goes outside the window, then it is rendered in this "wrong" position and only then it's corrected (at the end of the loop). The solution would be to firstly handle all corrections (updates) and then render content to the window.

Comment: The other thing could be that rotated rectangle has it's bounding box always axis-aligned. It means that when top-left corner of the rectangle was rotated clockwise, it will no longer be the most-left positioned corner and it's bounding box will change according to the transformation. I highly recommend reading [SFML documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/).

Comment: I agree, disabling rotation of the rectangle aligns the borders perfectly.

Comment: After applying the bounce, it's clear that my application of rotation is causing issues, do you have any solutions for that ?